# Regular expression to delete duplicated words?

Tags: regex

I use this to delete duplicated words (Notepad++ or Powergrep)
`(\b\w+\b)\W+\1.` replace with `${1}`.
How can this be changed to find nonconsecutive duplicated words **in one line** and delete second duplicated word?

```
Example
word1, word2, word1, word3,
Result
word1, word2, word3,
```

Tried this but then it select both duplicated words and strings beetwen them.

```
(\b\w+\b)(.*?)\W+\1.
```

Comment: This can't be easily done with regex. You could do this `((\b\w+\b).*)\b\2\b` repeatedly on the whole file until it finds no more duplicates, but it doesn't address any surrounding formatting. The other way is to split on whitespace, then recurse the array deleting dups, then rewrite the file.

Answer (score 5):

Looking ahead is easier using *lookahead* rather than looking behind.

```
\b(\w+)\b\s*,\s*(?=.*\1)
```

You can use this and replace by `empty string`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/24

Comment: Thanks, it works. Another problem, is there a way to limit the words by lenght? I am having problem that this regex will selects parts of the word, like for example word.1, will select ".1" as a word. 
Tried \b(\w+){4,10}\b\s*,\s*(?=.*\1) to limit the words by length but then it selects whole text.

Comment: @Jim8645 `\b(\w{4,10})\b\s*,\s*(?=.*\1)` use this to limit the length

Comment: It works, thanks, I figured how to find only numeric words or only alphabetic words, 
`\b(\w[0-9]{4,10})\b\s*,\s*(?=.*\1)`, 
`\b(\w[a-z]{4,10})\b\s*,\s*(?=.*\1)`,
but how to limit to find only links? for ex `http://www.google.com/abc`